I need help rendering the body of the menuItem "Player Select", while making the menuItem collapsable
I want the contents within menuItem "Player Select" to be collapsing, however what I have now is not rendering in the dashboard body. I am not sure if I need to change formatting, or if it is an issue on the server side. Any help is appreciated.
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "NBA Field Goal Analysis",
    titleWidth = 240
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 240,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Player Select",
        tabName = "selection",
        icon = icon("dashboard"),
        startExpanded = FALSE,
        selectInput(
          "player",
          "Select Player:",
          choices = sort(unique(nbaTotalShots$namePlayer)),
          selected = "Stephen Curry"
        ),
        uiOutput("season_type"),
        uiOutput("season_select")
      ),
      menuItem(
        "Year Comparison",
        tabName = "eras",
        icon = icon("calendar")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "selection",
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            column(
              width = 4,
              box(
                width = NULL,
                height = 450,
                uiOutput("profile")
              ),
              box(
                width = NULL,
                height = 250,
                htmlOutput("stats")
              )
            ),
            column(
              width = 8,
              box(
                width = NULL,
                selectInput(
                  "plot_type",
                  "Select Plot Type:",
                  choices = c("PPS", "xFG", "FGA"),
                  selected = "PPS"
                ),
                uiOutput("bio")
              ),
              box(
                width = NULL,
                plotOutput(
                  outputId = "court",
                  height = 600,
                  width = "100%"
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "eras",
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            box(
              width = 6,
              p("Select an Era")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

Here is what I am getting
Here is what I want, but I want the inputs in the sidebar to be collapsable under Player Select
